# .NET WCF SVC file downloaded instead of being executed

Tags: .net, wcf

I am using a WDF Service in my web application which I am accessing very jquery. Locally it works fine, but on my test server (IIS7) it does not.

I tried accessing the .svc via the url (www.mydomain.de/Services/MyService.svc) expecting that I get the same page as offline ("This is a WCF service, metadata publishing is disabled ....". Instead, the .svc file gets downloaded and opens in Visual Studio.

Is this a web.config problem (it works offline but I don't have II7 offline) or is it a problem that file associations in IIs7 are not correct?
My Testserver is running in a shared hosting environment and I have only very limited access (Parallels Plesk Panel 9), so if this is an IIS7 problem I need to go through the webhoster...

Any Feedback welcome.

Comment: You have verified that the right version of .NET is installed on that server?

Comment: But not fully registered or someone deleted the registration for .svc files, so asp.net does not execute them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the web.config.... on the machine level. Can be the regtistration for .svc files got delted. Limited access means likely the hoster, out of idiocy, cluelessness of due to a business decision simply did not enable / disabled .svc files. Without the registration... the file will be "served" (transmitted).

Not a lot you can do - take it with their support. .NET 4.0 may not be properly installed. or, as I said, it is a willfull decision.

The fact that they use IIS 7 says a lot - they should use 7.5 for quite a time now.

Comment: Ok, we are just checking this and you seem to be right. How would the .svc entry look like? I couldn't find an example how it looks originally before it gets "lost"...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend re-registering the .NET framework 4.0 with IIS using the aspnet_regiis.exe tool

Comment: Hm, webhoster told me he did that, without success